# Debugging javascript events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-select2

Is there any way to have some kind of a call stack of events that occur on a web page?

After i added a `select2` widget on a web page, I started experiencing lots of "too much recursion" errors but from what i can see in the code, there is no obvious event bubble issues (checked [jQuery too much recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320157/jquery-too-much-recursion))

*The errors occur after clicking basically anywhere on the page (after a certain delay)*

I tried preventing event bubble manually with `event.stopPropagation` but that doesn't seem to be doing any good.

I even wrote a bunch of `console.log` in every possible culprit but everything looks normal in the output.

So it would be really nice to have a quick way to track down what events are being called (on which nodes and if possible, what handlers are invoked).

Any ideas? Thanks.

**Details:**

- Firebug error:

```
too much recursion

...s?3:4&s?2:0),e}},special:{load:{noBubble:!0},focus:{trigger:function(){if(this!=...
```

- Select 2 jQuery code:

```
$("#my-input").select2({
        width: 200,
        placeholder: "Enter a name",
        minimumInputLength: 0,
        ajax: {
            url: "/ajax/search",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: function(term, page) {
                return {
                    q: term
                }
            },
            results: function(bond, page){
                return {
                    results: bond, 
                    more: false
                }
            }
        },
        formatResult: function(bond) {
            return '' + bond.name + ''
        },
        formatSelection: function(bond) {
            return bond.name
        },
        initSelection: function(elem, cb) {
            return elem
        }
    });
```

- Stack trace in Chrome dev tools:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the call stack trace in devtools?

Comment: Did you try updating to the latest git source?

Comment: @elclanrs umm im not sure which one you are referring to but if it's the one in Chrome, yes i did, and the last 3 calls were to `x.fn.extend.find`, `x.fn.x.init`, `x` (updated question with a screenshot)

Comment: double check those lines and they point to the same snippet that firebug displayed.

Comment: You can try to skip through your code by adding `debugger;` before your *select2*-call...

Comment: everything looks normal during the step through.. as a side note, the errors appear mostly appear after random clicks on the page (ie the click doesn't even need to be on an element with event handlers attached to it..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are browser extensions which provide this functionality:

- [EventBug Firefox Extension](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#Eventbug)
- [Visual Event](https://github.com/DataTables/VisualEvent)
- [Visual Event Chromium Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-event/pbmmieigblcbldgdokdjpioljjninaim)

Comment: Thank you for responding even if it has been a while, it's definitely helpful