# jquery UI slider, change event show *too much recursion*

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
$( "#slider-1" ).slider({
        min: 1,
        step: 0.01,
        max: 3,
        value: 2,
        animate:"slow",
        orientation: "horizontal",
        change: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).slider('value', Math.round(ui.value));
            ui.preventDefault();
        }
    })
```

This show **too much recursion** error in console how fix it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This is due to `eventBubling`. You should check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320157/jquery-too-much-recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that issue myself, by changing the code as below.

```
var rounded_value='';

    $( "#slider-1" ).slider({
        min: 1,
        step: 0.01,
        max: 3,
        value: 2,
        animate:"slow",
        orientation: "horizontal",
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if(rounded_value!=ui.value){
                rounded_value=ui.value;
                $(this).slider('value', Math.round(ui.value));  
            }
            return false;
        }
    })
```